# Why a segfault is thrown in this code?

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, semaphore, free

Why does the below code throw a segmentation fault? If I remove the line sem_post(sem) or free(malloc(65536)) then segfault is not thrown. Also, what does free(malloc(65536)) exactly mean?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int
main()
{
  sem_t *sem = (sem_t *)malloc(sizeof(sem_t)); 
  sem_init(sem, 0, 0);
  sem_post(sem);
  sem_wait(sem);
  sem_destroy(sem);
  free(sem);
  sem_post(sem);
  free(malloc(65536));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't even understand the purpose of `free(malloc(65536));` *What does it mean?* It allocates that memory and immediately releases it (even if the allocation fails).

Comment: After free(sem), sem is no longer exists. free(sem) has to come after sem_post().   free(malloc()) doesn't make a sense at all.

Comment: `sem_post(sem);` *uses* `sem`, while you already destroyed and freed it.

Comment: First time that I see `free` and `malloc` on the same line.,..

Comment: Why is there no segfault when I remove the line free(malloc(65536)) and run it using - gcc -pthread test.c && ./a.out

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `sem_post(sem);` after `free(sem);`. `free` is a function that frees up the memory your program is using and returns it to the OS for use in another program. Calling any function on a pointer that has been freed is [undefined behavior (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Further, once you have called `sem_destroy` on a semaphore as you have done, it is no longer a valid semaphore and should not be used as such until and unless you re-initialize it via `sem_init`.

Comment: Quibble: `free()` does not necessarily return the memory *to the OS*, and in practice, it typically doesn't.  It *does* make that memory available at least to serve other allocations by the same process, though, and dereferencing `sem` (as `sem_post()` must do) after it was freed definitely invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Even more of a problem, though, is calling `sem_post()` after having performed a `sem_destroy()` on the semaphore.  The memory for `sem` may still appear to have the same contents after a `free()`, but those contents definitely are not a useable semaphore, that space having been processed by `sem_destroy()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Regarding the "return to the OS" part, you're right that the actual story is a bit more complicated - only "larger" memory allocations are actually returned, while "smaller" memory allocations are available to serve other allocations on the same process, as you said. I just went with a simplistic explanation so as to avoid over-explaining. You're correct on the `sem_destroy` front as well; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Why is there no segfault when I remove the line free(malloc(65536)) and run it using - gcc -pthread test.c && ./a.out

Comment: @DhruvShekhawat: Because using `sem` at all after freeing it is undefined behavior. By definition, your compiler is allowed to create an executable that will work exactly as you expected it to or one that crashes every other time you run it, or one that crashes always. Read the link about undefined behavior in my answer; it is rather informative.